# Schedule task for every 4 hours in Node.js

Tags: node.js

How could I schedule a task to run after 4 hours using "node-schedule" in Node.js
Currently my code is as below but it isn't responding as expected.

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var task = schedule.scheduleJob('* */4 * * *', function () {
    console.log('Scheduled Task');
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your syntax creates a cron that runs every minute every 4 hours.

The syntax you are looking for is `0 */4 * * *`. Wich executes ONCE every 4 hours.

You can test the cron syntax with the website http://crontab.guru

Another option setting your cron in node is using rules. See https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule

```
var cron = require('node-schedule');
var rule = new cron.RecurrenceRule();
rule.hour = 4;
rule.minute = 0;
cron.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
    console.log(new Date(), 'Every 4 hours');
});
```

Comment: The rules-based option here causes it to run daily at 4am, not every four hours. To accomplish every-four-hour behavior using rules, you need to construct a Range with a step value.

Comment: Also, "every minute every 4 hours" is unclear; the original expression runs every minute during every _hour that is evenly divisible by four_. In other words, it will run at 12:00, 12:01, 12:02, ..., 12:59, and then wait until 4:00, then 4:01, 4:02, ..., 4:59, then 8:00, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var cron = require('node-schedule');
var rule = new cron.RecurrenceRule();
rule.hour = new cron.Range(0,23,4);
rule.minute = 0;
cron.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
    console.log(new Date(), 'Every 4 hours');
});
```

new cron.Range(0,23,4); 4 is the optional step parameter