# JS/JSON create a new line for data every hour

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

Lately i've found myself toying with DiscordJS and some of it's functionality for logging. I know the method i am going for is way outdated and shouldn't fully be trusted for actively changing data but i am curious.

```
let count = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./data.json", "utf8"));
let cid = 'channelID';

client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.channel.id !== cid) return;
  if (message.channel.id === cid) {
    if(!count[message.channel.id === cid]) count[message.channel.id === cid] = {
      count: 0
    }
    let xData = count[message.channel.id === cid];
    xData.count++;
    fs.writeFile("./data.json", JSON.stringify(count), (err) => {
      if (err) console.error(err)
    });
  }

});
```

This all works for a base usage. It adds on as needed, i am just curious as to how i could make a new line every hour in the JSON file.

```
{"true"{"count":1}}
```

I don't have a huge amount of experience with JS and JSON in the same project. I am looking for a way to create a new line every hour and label the corresponding hour.

This is for logging of activity, not logging of messages. I have that covered completely. (adding this to draw back confusion)

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503557/schedule-task-for-every-4-hours-in-node-js

Comment: I had looked over that thread, my issue is it would just repeat the task and update.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`setInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) Method

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 30000); // 30 sec.
```